# Cross compile qemu for android error

Tags: android, cross-compiling, qemu

I am using ndk-10e to compile the qemu2.5.0. I've successfully compiled glib for android. My configure command is this:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$SYSROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure -- 
prefix="$SYSROOT/usr" --target-list=arm-linux-user --disable-system -- 
disable-bsd-user --disable-tools --disable-zlib-test --cross- 
prefix="arm-linux-androideabi-" --cc="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux- 
androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" - 
-host-cc="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux- 
x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" --cpu="arm" -- 
cxx="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux- 
x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++" --extra-ldflags="-fPIE -pie -- 
sysroot $SYSROOT -L$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi- 
4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/ - 
L$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/ - 
L$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib" --extra-cflags="-fPIE - 
pie --sysroot $SYSROOT -I$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu- 
libstdc++/4.9/include -I$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu- 
libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include -L$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu- 
libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/" --disable-guest-agent
```

When I type in "make", it gives me this error.

```
>   CHK version_gen.h
  CC    arm-linux-user/linux-user/syscall.o
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:374:16: error: static declaration of 'gettid' follows non-static declaration
 _syscall0(int, gettid)
                ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:303:13: note: in definition of macro '_syscall0'
 static type name (void)   \
             ^
In file included from /home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:27:0:
/home/sam/Documents/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:57:15: note: previous declaration of 'gettid' was here
 extern pid_t  gettid(void) __pure2;
               ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'gettid':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:374:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'syscall' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 _syscall0(int, gettid)
 ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:374:1: warning: nested extern declaration of 'syscall' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'lock_iovec':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2050:30: error: 'IOV_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (count  IOV_MAX) {
                              ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2050:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'target_to_host_ipc_perm':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2703:12: error: 'struct ipc_perm' has no member named '__key'
     host_ip->__key = tswap32(target_ip->__key);
            ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2716:12: error: 'struct ipc_perm' has no member named '__seq'
     host_ip->__seq = tswap16(target_ip->__seq);
            ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'host_to_target_ipc_perm':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2731:39: error: 'struct ipc_perm' has no member named '__key'
     target_ip->__key = tswap32(host_ip->__key);
                                       ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2744:39: error: 'struct ipc_perm' has no member named '__seq'
     target_ip->__seq = tswap16(host_ip->__seq);
                                       ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: At top level:
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2815:7: error: redefinition of 'union semun'
 union semun {
       ^
In file included from /home/sam/Documents/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/sem.h:32:0,
                 from /home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:59:
/home/sam/Documents/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/sem.h:55:7: note: originally defined here
 union semun {
       ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'target_to_host_semarray':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2840:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'semctl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ret = semctl(semid, 0, IPC_STAT, semun);
     ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2840:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'semctl' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_semop':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3002:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'semop' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return get_errno(semop(semid, sops, nsops));
     ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3002:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'semop' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'target_to_host_msqid_ds':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3041:12: error: 'struct msqid_ds' has no member named '__msg_cbytes'
     host_md->__msg_cbytes = tswapal(target_md->__msg_cbytes);
            ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'host_to_target_msqid_ds':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3062:46: error: 'struct msqid_ds' has no member named '__msg_cbytes'
     target_md->__msg_cbytes = tswapal(host_md->__msg_cbytes);
                                              ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_msgctl':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3114:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'msgctl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(msgctl(msgid, cmd, &dsarg));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3114:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'msgctl' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_msgsnd':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3157:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'msgsnd' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ret = get_errno(msgsnd(msqid, host_mb, msgsz, msgflg));
     ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3157:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'msgsnd' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_msgrcv':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3177:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'msgrcv' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ret = get_errno(msgrcv(msqid, host_mb, msgsz, msgtyp, msgflg));
     ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3177:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'msgrcv' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_shmctl':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3302:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'shmctl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(shmctl(shmid, cmd, &dsarg));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3302:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'shmctl' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_shmat':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3343:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'shmat' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         host_raddr = shmat(shmid, (void *)g2h(shmaddr), shmflg);
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3343:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'shmat' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3343:20: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
         host_raddr = shmat(shmid, (void *)g2h(shmaddr), shmflg);
                    ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3353:24: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
             host_raddr = shmat(shmid, g2h(mmap_start), shmflg | SHM_REMAP);
                        ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_shmdt':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3391:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'shmdt' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return get_errno(shmdt(g2h(shmaddr)));
     ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3391:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'shmdt' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_ipc':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3413:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'semget' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(semget(first, second, third));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3413:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'semget' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3426:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'msgget' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(msgget(first, second));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3426:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'msgget' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3484:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'shmget' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ret = get_errno(shmget(first, second, third));
  ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:3484:2: warning: nested extern declaration of 'shmget' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c: In function 'do_syscall':
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6241:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'stime' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             ret = get_errno(stime(&host_time));
             ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6241:13: warning: nested extern declaration of 'stime' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6318:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'futimesat' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             ret = get_errno(futimesat(arg1, path(p), tvp));
             ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6318:13: warning: nested extern declaration of 'futimesat' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6686:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigorset' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             sigorset(&set, &set, &cur_set);
             ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6686:13: warning: nested extern declaration of 'sigorset' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6870:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigtimedwait' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             ret = get_errno(sigtimedwait(&set, &uinfo, puts));
             ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6870:13: warning: nested extern declaration of 'sigtimedwait' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6908:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sethostname' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(sethostname(p, arg2));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:6908:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'sethostname' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:7627:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'vhangup' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(vhangup());
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:7627:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'vhangup' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:7794:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'setdomainname' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(setdomainname(p, arg2));
         ^
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:7794:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'setdomainname' [-Wnested-externs]
/home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:9280:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'readahead' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         ret = get_errno(readahead(arg1, ((off64_t)arg3
```

There are some weird thing like

> /home/sam/Documents/qemu-2.5.0/linux-user/syscall.c:2703:12: error: 'struct ipc_perm' has no member named '__key'
>        host_ip->__key = tswap32(target_ip->__key);
>   which I don't know how to fix it. Anyone can help?

Comment: Um, you might have gone a bit overboard with all that text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a mixture of:

- 2.5 is a pretty old version of QEMU; you may be running into bugs in compilation with newer/different versions of libc that are already fixed upstream. Start by using a newer version.
- You're building against the Android libc (bionic), which isn't a tested or supported libc to build against. Where it has differences or idiosyncracies compared to glibc (the standard Linux libc) you'll need to change QEMU to work around those.

For instance with that error about __key, the problem is that Bionic names its version of that field in struct ipc_perm "key", not "__key".

Comment: Yeah. That's it. After I changed all those things it finally worked.